# Run django-celery tests on Django 1.8

Tags: testing, django-celery, django-1.8

Ultimately, I want to get the tests to pass for Django 1.9. `django-celery` currently works with Django < 1.9. So the first step is to make sure that the library tests are passing with Django 1.8 on my machine.

I've cloned https://github.com/celery/django-celery in a testing project and installed the requirements. For Django 1.7 the tests are passing. For Django 1.8 I'm getting the same error several times while it should work...

See `https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/tox.ini` includes Django 1.8:

```
...
1.8: Django>=1.8.0,<1.9.0
```

---

For Django 1.7:

```
pip install Django==1.7
./django-celery/tests/manage.py test djcelery.tests
...
Ran 64 tests in 0.319s
OK
```

---

For Django 1.8:

```
pip install Django==1.8
./django-celery/tests/manage.py test djcelery.tests

...
======================================================================
ERROR: test_all_as_schedule (djcelery.tests.test_schedulers.test_DatabaseScheduler)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/francois/web/test_project/django-celery/djcelery/tests/test_schedulers.py", line 110, in setUp
    m1 = create_model_interval(schedule(timedelta(seconds=10)))
  File "/Users/francois/web/test_project/django-celery/djcelery/tests/test_schedulers.py", line 20, in create_model_interval
    **kwargs)
  File "/Users/francois/web/test_project/django-celery/djcelery/tests/test_schedulers.py", line 40, in create_model
    return Model(**dict(entry, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/francois/Envs/test_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 468, in __init__
    setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
  File "/Users/francois/Envs/test_project/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 668, in __set__
    (value, self.field.rel.to._meta.object_name)
ValueError: Cannot assign "<IntervalSchedule: every 10.0 seconds>": "IntervalSchedule" instance isn't saved in the database.


 ...
 Ran 64 tests in 0.150s

 FAILED (errors=15)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Hi François, the `django-celery` project is deprecated (Django support is now directly included in the `celery` package). Is there a specific reason for you wanting to validate Django 1.9 support?

Comment: Yes, I was working on a fairly big and old project using `django-celery`. I want to take advantage of some Django 1.9 features . It sounds like I better remove it than upgrade it though.

Answer (score 0):

Django 1.8 had an API change that prevents adding unsaved model instances as a ForeignKey: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#assigning-unsaved-objects-to-relations-raises-an-error